# Open XML for Microsoft Word Professional 2007

Tags: vsto, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordml

I currently have a `VSTO` project using Visual Studio 2010 for Microsoft Offcie Word 2007 Professional .NET 4.0.  The project works well but is slow to load and populate the data using the VSTO methods.  A faster method would be to use the Open XML methods.  However, I am using VSTO methods to insert WordML snippets using VSTO.

> Example: Tools.RichTextContentControl.Range.InsertXML(string WordML)

Does anyone know of a way to insert WordML using the Open XML methods ?
All example I see are how to insert plain text but not formatted WordML.

Answer (score 0):

OpenXML can be used similar to using XML in C#.
Refer this Msdn link for using XML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195.aspx

One example where the WordML has been used like XML.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/02/26/open-xml-sdk-office-services-better-together.aspx